# Build Settings : What changes should I do in the build settings so that on releasing the app it will show the languages on App Store as only English?

Tags: ios, localization, internationalization, app-store-connect, build-settings

I have committed some kinda mistake in uploading an iOS app, which makes my app show the languages as English and German on AppStore.

The scenario is that I have set the "Localization native development region" key in (info.plist of target) to Germany, while my app is actually an English app(for all territories). But I am not confirmed that changing this key to US, can change the Appstore language of the app to only to English.

Besides this, I have also set the language in Localizations in the( info of Project) to:
1. English - Development Language
2. German

What changes should I do in the settings so that on releasing the app it will show the languages on App Store as only English?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing an experiment with uploading an application to app store, I came to know that for the languages of the application we need some settings changes in the info.plist of the project(remember not the target).

For eg. For Multilingual(English and German both) apps. It should
show only these two languages in the App Store. Otherwise the user might get irritated after downloading the app when he see the content is in single language.[image: Info.plist settings]

Just go in the localization as shown in screenshot above and click on + to add
a language and - to remove the language.

Also this localisation language setting creates a folder named "de.Iproj" or  "en.Iproj" for respective languages. That folder must also be removed from the build if the corresponding language localization does not exist