# Languages appear in iTunesConnect that I didn't add

Tags: ios, localization, app-store-connect

I have an iOS project. I didn't localize it in any language but when I submit it iTunesConnect it shows multiple languages. I am not adding language in iTunes only English.

How can I remove these languages from my app.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please go to the following link as I already faced the problem as well as I found the answer and posted it here:

[How to change the languages of app, that can be seen on App Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35768199/build-settings-what-changes-should-i-do-in-the-build-settings-so-that-on-relea)